# Is there a formula to take outliers (values that are a way out of my mean and not in numerical series) from a column in dataframe - Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, outliers

Assume that you have these values for a column in a dataframe: modelo['a'] = **2, 3, 5, 7**, 2510, 2530, 2550, 2570, 2590, 2610, 2613, 2615, 2617, 2630.

What I see as outliers are: 2, 3, 5, 7 (way out of a mean) **and 2613, 2615, 2617 (not matching with numerical series)**.

- I have tried this function to take these numbers (2, 3, 5, 7) out:

```
outlier = []
def detect_outlier():
    mean = np.mean(modelo['a'])
    std = np.std(modelo['a'])

    for number in modelo['a']:
        a_score = (number - mean)/std
        if np.abs(ascore) > 2:
            outlier.append(number)
    return outlier
```

- **The problem is the following:** I need to take these numbers **(2613, 2615, 2617) as well,** but I can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is to get the mode while subtracting each element of a list. After that I subtracted each element of a list and If this number does not match with mode... you found your "outlier"..:

```
modex = mode(np.diff(modeloa['X'].unique()))
modey = mode(np.diff(modeloa['Y'].unique()))
modez = mode(np.diff(modeloa['Z'].unique()))

for numberx, numbery, numberz in zip(modeloa['X'].unique(),modeloa['Y'].unique(),modeloa['Z'].unique()):
    if numberx + modex not in modeloa['X'].unique() and numberx - modex not in modeloa['X'].unique():
        modeloa = modeloa[modeloa['X'] != numberx]
        print("This coordinate in X-axis is not in the center of the block: " + str(numberx))
        
    if numbery + modey not in modeloa['Y'].unique() and numbery - modey not in modeloa['Y'].unique():
        modeloa = modeloa[modeloa['Y'] != numbery]
        print("This coordinate in Y-axis is not in the center of the block: " + str(numbery))
        
    if numberz + modez not in modeloa['Z'].unique() and numberz - modez not in modeloa['Z'].unique():
        modelob = modeloa[modeloa['Z'] != numberz]
        print("This coordinate in Z-axis is not in the center of the block: " + str(numberz))
```